# Annotation String[] oneArr(); vs String[][] twoArr(); declaration

Tags: java, arrays, annotations

I have an annotaion of following types:

```
 public @interface A {
   String[] oneArr();
   String[][] twoArr();
 }
```

Why is the first type `String[] oneArr();` valid, but second type  `String[][] twoArr();` is invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JLS (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6):

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.

Here is the error message from the Eclipse java compiler which is a little more clear:

> Invalid type String[][] for the annotation attribute A.twoArr; only
>   primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted
>   or 1-dimensional arrays thereof

Comment: To clarify: `whose element type is one of the preceding types` means that only arrays of primitives, Strings, classes, enums or annotations are allowed, not arrays of arrays  - which is the case for `String[][]`.